# How to fix pip install error permission denied inside conda environment

Tags: python, pip

Im trying to install some packages for a project using an exported yml environment file I've been given.

During the installation with conda env create , the pip section of the yml didn't install any of the packages and I had to install them 1 by 1. Activated my environment and starting searching for each package to install with conda or conda-forge or pip.

3 of the packages required pip to install so I installed pip into my environment and then I used pip install which gave me errors of this type:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'classified_information_/myusername/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_1.0.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pretrainedmodels-0.7.4.dist-info/INSTALLEReb1alm63.tmp'
```

im using python3.7 if that helps and I want to add these 3 packages :

```
insightface
mxnet-cu100mkl
pretrainedmodels
```

all 3 had that type of problem and keep inmind I am not the owner of the pc ,im just a student thats allowed to use the machine for testing purposes so Sudo rights is not sth I own

Is there anything I can do?

**EDIT:**

I tried using the full path to pip doing anaconda3/envs/pytorch_1.0.1/bin/pip install  which worked for insightface and pretrained models but im still getting an error with mxnet :

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/classified/myusername/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_1.0.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/graphviz-0.8.4.dist-info/INSTALLERh4uallts.tmp'